# How does it look in unminified version?

Tags: javascript, minify

how I can translate marked part to non-minified version?
It is minified Javascript:

```
function a(t, i){
   var u = null;
   t && (u = translate(t, i)); // <- This line
   //What value be 't'? And when 'u' will be translate(t, i)?
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
t && (u = translate(t, i));
```

...is taking advantage of the fact that boolean operators will short circuit once they can not possibly be true. So that code is the same as

```
if (t) {
    u = translate(t, i)
}
```

EDIT:

> Ok thanks, and what about this please:

```
return te && te.translate ? te.translate(e, t, n) : t || e
```

That means:

```
if (te && te.translate) {
  return te.translate(e, t, n);
} else {
  return t || e;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, and what about this please:  `return te && te.translate ? te.translate(e, t, n) : t || e`

Comment: @D3admau5 Your question should be in your question; additional comments should not ask new questions

Comment: more simpler last return analogy: `return t ? t : e;`